# Database schema restores by Sql job

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

im planing to do the database backup and restore by using sql Job 
my database size is to large and i want to backup and restore my schema only - this is no purpose for the backup data

by using this code i can set up sql job 
can anyone help me to backup and restore my schema only  ??

```
BACKUP DATABASE [pubs] 
TO DISK = N'c:\temp\backups\pubs_full.bak' 
WITH INIT, SKIP, CHECKSUM
GO


RESTORE DATABASE pubs_RestoreTest
FROM DISK = N'c:\temp\backups\pubs_full.bak'
WITH MOVE 'pubs' TO 'c:\temp\backups\pubs_RestoreTest.mdf',
MOVE 'pubs_log' TO 'C:\temp\backups\pubs_RestoreTest_log.ldf'
```

Comment: This isn't possible in SQL. You _can_ however backup files and filegroups one at a time so if you ensure all data in the schema goes on one file you can back up just the filegroup. Focus on filegroups and files, not schemas. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179401(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: ant other idea looking for more reply

Comment: If you want more input you could put a bounty on or move the the DBA stack overflow

Comment: ok thanks boro i will move it to DBA